# How to convert bits to bytes TCL

Tags: tcl, byte, bit

I would like to convert bits to bytes in TCL and i dont know how do this.
I have a variable which get datas from file. Next i converted this string to bits so, I've got:

```
0100000101011010011000011000101001111000001101101000001001000101011010010001101100110110001110000011100000111001001110010110100101001111
```

Next i want to partitioned as 8 bits each and i dont know how.

I put this bits in to variable `$dataBits.` 
I created list:

```
set lista [list $dataBits]
```

Sorry, but i am noob and i learn tcl.

Greetings,
Michael

Comment: 1 Byte is 8 bits. Do you want your input to be partitioned as 8 bits each ?

Comment: Please mark an answer as accepted (click the tickmark) if one answer worked for you. This will also mark your problem as resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert binary number string to decimal value via [expr](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/expr.htm) or [scan](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/scan.htm) command:

```
set val "01110010"
puts [expr { "0b$val" }]; # print "114"
puts [scan $val %b]; # print "114"
```

To convert binary number string to byte/char you can use [binary format](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/binary.htm) command:

```
set val "0111001001110010"
puts [binary format B* $val]; # print "rr"
```

Comment: but i need partitioned as 8 bits each

Comment: If you want to convert bits to bytes/chars then you don't need to split string to octets. `binary format B*` convert to byte every 8 bits.

Answer (score 0):

```
set bits 0100000101011010011000011000101001111000001101101000001001000101011010010001101100110110001110000011100000111001001110010110100101001111
set bytes {}
for {set i 0} {$i < [string length $bits]} {incr i 8} {
    lappend bytes [string range $bits $i $i+7]
}
```

This solution simply visits every 8th character position in the bit string and copies eight characters from that position into a string that is appended to the list in `bytes`.

Documentation:
[< (operator)](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/expr.htm),
[for](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/for.htm),
[incr](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/incr.htm),
[lappend](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lappend.htm),
[set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm),
[string](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/string.htm)

*Syntax of Tcl index expressions:*

- *integer* zero-based index number
- `end` the last element
- `end`*-N* the *n*th element before the last element
- `end`*+N* the *n*th element after the last element (in practice, *N* should be negative)
- *M-N* the *n*th element before element *m*
- *M+N* the *n*th element after element *m*

There can be no whitespace within the expression.

Answer (score 0):

For partitioning, you can use `regexp` as well.

```
set bits {0100000101011010011000011000101001111000001101101000001001000101011010010001101100110110001110000011100000111001001110010110100101001111}
% regexp -inline -all {[01]{1,8}} $bits
01000001 01011010 01100001 10001010 01111000 00110110 10000010 01000101 01101001 00011011 00110110 00111000 00111000 00111001 00111001 01101001 01001111
% # Even if they are even not in the form of multiples of 8, it will work as well 
% set bits 1010101001
1010101001
% regexp -inline -all {[01]{1,8}} $bits
10101010 01
%
```

Comment: Thank you! i will try it :)

Comment: You could use `regexp -inline -all {.{1,8}} $bits` for the same effect. If we know the input is only 0s and 1s, there's no need to validate them in the re.